# How to replace everything except 100 characters before and after a given string?

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to filter a set of data and I have to deal with multiple entries of `~5000` characters.

What I need is 100 characters before and after some `keyword`.

I have looked into regex code for search and replace but only found functions to get one `keyword`, not the surrounding characters.

Example Input:

```
abc123cde345fgh678ijk910keywordbc123cde345fgh678ijk910
```

Desired output with `+-5` characters:

```
jk910keywordbc123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match 100 characters, followed by the keyword, followed by 100 more characters:

```js
const str = 'abc123cde345fgh678ijk910keywordbc123cde345fgh678ijk910';
const match = str.match(/.{5}keyword.{5}/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

If you need to construct the pattern dynamically, then:

```js
const str = 'abc123cde345fgh678ijk910keywordbc123cde345fgh678ijk910';
const keyword = 'keyword';
const pattern = new RegExp(`.{5}${keyword}.{5}`);
const match = str.match(pattern);
console.log(match[0]);
```

If the pattern may contain characters with a special meaning in a regular expression, like `$`, then make sure to escape them first before passing to `new RegExp`:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
const escape = s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

const str = 'abc123cde345fgh678ijk910keyw$ordbc123cde345fgh678ijk910';
const keyword = 'keyw$ord';
const pattern = new RegExp(`.{5}${escape(keyword)}.{5}`);
const match = str.match(pattern);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this can be implemented using [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to search the index of the `keyword` inside the input `string`, and then use [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get the chars between a particular radius.

```js
const str = 'abc123cde345fgh678ijk910keywordbc123cde345fgh678ijk910';

const getKeyword = (str, keyword, radius) =>
{
    let idx = str.indexOf(keyword);
    return str.slice(idx - radius, idx + keyword.length + radius);
}

console.log(getKeyword(str, "keyword", 5));
console.log(getKeyword(str, "keyword", 15));
console.log(getKeyword(str, "keyword", 1000));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note this will also work when the `radius` is greater than the maximum possible, returning the entire string in this case.